# Inputstream and Outputstream with reading a list of files

Tags: java, inputstream, fileoutputstream

I have this ArrayList files

```
for(File file : files){

    InputStream in = FileInputStream(file);
    // process each file and save it to file
    OutputStream out = FileOutputStream(file);
    try{

    } finally {
       in.close();
       out.close();
    }
}
```

the performance is really slow since every loop there is a in/out close(), is there a better way to do this? I tried to put outputstream oustide of the loop, it doesn't work.

Comment: hmm... but it should atleast be faster when multiple files are read simultaneously... on different threads... if you are reading a lot of files.. then this should make sense

Comment: (What happens if you `new FileOutputStream` throws an exception (possible an `FileNotFoundException` but possibly an unchecked exception)? Same for `in.close();`. You want one `try`-`finally` per resource.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using buffered streams makes a *huge* difference.

Try this:

```
for(final File file : files) {

    final InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    final OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(...)));
    try {
        // Process each file and save it to file
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
        try {
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

Note that the `IOException`s that can be thrown when closing the streams must be ignored, or you will lose the potential initial exception.

Another problem is that both streams are on the same file, which doesn't work. So I suppose you're using two different files.

Comment: I am trying this and get back to you about result

Comment: I suggest sticking to one `try`-`finally` per underlying resource. If `new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(...)))` throws an exception, you got a mess. If closing the output stream, say, throws an exception you've just gone and created a corrupt file and ignored it. There's probably other thing wrong, but if you do it in the non-clever way, everything just works and you don't need to think about it.

Comment: just tried, and the result is twice faster than previous version, and it won't consume any space up.

Answer (score 1):

A close() can take up to 20 ms. I doubt this is your program unless you have 1000's of files.

I suspect your performance problem is a lack of buffering the input and output.  Can you show your buffering wrappers as well?

Comment: outputfile is about 200MB, so it closes 200mb file every loop, does that cause slow?

Comment: close() closes flush() so flushing to disk (up to) 100Mb would slow it down yes.

Comment: If you have a disk you are reading/writing to, you should expect it to read/write at about 30 MB per second.  If you are reading & writing 200 MB, that should take about 13 second. 200*2/30.  Is that how long it is taking?

Comment: It ate all my /temp in c:\, anyway I think buffer solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can of course build a queue of OutputStreams  and offload that to a background thread that handles the closing of these outputstreams. Same for InputStreams.
Alternatively you can leave it down to the JVM to do that -- simply don't close the files and leave it to the GC to do that when objects are finalized.

Comment: so you mean I don't have to close() ?

Comment: it's not about "have to" -- as that all depends on the context. I personally *wouldn't* leave the close() to the jvm, however you *could* do that.

Comment: If you try splitting across threads you may actually a performance decrease with I/O. Particularly if it happens to run of those old rotating-media electro-mechanical devices. (Although you get buffering, think of the poor little heads zipping around like they've lost their chickens.)